# Creating MVC Delete button extension - How To Extend MVC's Html helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

ASP.NET MVC 2 renders a link (i.e. `<a>`) to delete records.

It can be harmful to allow delete actions through GET actions, so I want to do the delete by issuing a POST.

I've created the following piece of code:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Boodschap", new { id = item.BoodschapID }))
    { %>
    <button>Delete</button>
<% } %>
```

Now I would like to add this code to the Html helper as an extension method:

```
public static MvcForm DeleteButton(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, 
    string actionName, string controllerName, string routeValues)
{
    MvcForm form = helper.BeginForm(actionName, controllerName, routeValues);
    return form;
}
```

Now here is where I got stuck. How do I get this delete button to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to generate the full code, you're going about it wrong to have it return an `MvcForm`.  You want to have it return an `MvcHtmlString` and construct the HTML within the method.  That way you can use it as:

```
@Html.DeleteButton( "Delete", "Boodschap", new { id = item.BoodschapID } );
```

Generating the HTML directly (note: untested, you may need suitable null checks, etc.)

```
public static MvcHtmlString DeleteButton( this HtmlHelper helper, string name, 
    string actionName, object htmlAttributes )
{
     return DeleteButton( helper, name, actionName, null, null, htmlAttributes );
}

public static MvcHtmlString DeleteButton( this HtmlHelper helper, string name, 
    string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, 
    object htmlAttributes )
{
     var buttonBuilder = new TagBuilder("button");
     buttonBuilder.SetInnerText( name );

     var formBuilder = new TagBuilder("form");
     var urlHelper = new UrlHelper( helper.ViewContext.RequestContext );
     formBuilder.Attributes.Add( "action", urlHelper.Action( 
         actionName, controllerName, routeValues ) )
     formBuilder.Attributes.Add( "method", FormMethod.Post );
     formBuilder.MergeAttributes( new RouteValueDictionary( htmlAttributes ) );
     formBuilder.InnerHtml = buttonBuilder.ToString();

     return new MvcHtmlString( formBuilder.ToString() );
}
```

An alternative would be to reuse the form helpers and Response.Write, but have the method return an (empty) string, perhaps something like:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DeleteButton(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, string actionName, object routeValues)
{
    return DeleteButton(helper, name, actionName, null, routeValues, null);
}

public static MvcHtmlString DeleteButton(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
{
    using (helper.BeginForm(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes))
    {
        var response = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response;
        var builder = new TagBuilder("button");
        builder.SetInnerText(name);
        response.Write(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Create("");
}
```

Comment: I've edited the last answer which - after some changes - seems to work correctly.

Comment: Very nice insight in how to do a `response.Write` in the HtmlHelper. Thanks!! Wish I could vote it up again.

Answer (score 1):

While I think that a `<form>` element will do the trick, it isn't very AJAX-y.

Rather, why not use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [wire up to the click event](http://api.jquery.com/click/) for the appropriate `<a>` links, and then [issue an HTTP POST to the server yourself](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)?

```
$document.ready(function () {
    // "deleteLink is a class that identifies links that
    // are used for deleting, you might have some other mechanism
    $("a .deleteLink").click(function () { 
        $.post('post url', function(data) {
            // Do something with the data returned
        });    
    });
});
```

The advantage to this is you keep your HTML *much* cleaner than if you inserted a `<form>` for every item you wanted to delete, and semantically-relevant, clean markup is always a plus from a development, SEO and other perspectives.

Comment: I like the idea of using some sort of ajax post. The argument of cleaner HTML sticks in my head. I don't know if that is the goal of a business app. Ever since I read http://www.hanselman.com/blog/JavaScriptIsAssemblyLanguageForTheWebSematicMarkupIsDeadCleanVsMachinecodedHTML.aspx, I've been wondering is business apps should even attend to write clean html.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: I wouldn't say it's a goal, but cleaner HTML is a goal of good development practices IMO; when faced with a wall of HTML, it's going to be a nightmare to wade through it all to see where something went wrong; with jQuery (or something similar) you have a better separation of concerns; additionally, you are using battle-tested code.  Finally, you'll have more people out in the wild who can help when you are all following the same paradigm as opposed to trying to figure out the niche case yourself because you digressed.

Comment: I'm in favor of handling it via AJAX, but this will break if there's a javascript error on the page or javascript is turned off.  You could intercept the form submits with the handler and do it via AJAX -- or even unwrap the forms leaving only the buttons with a suitable handler if need be.

Comment: @tvanfosson: I agree that breaking because of a javascript error on the page is a risk, but with tools like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), and frameworks, the likelihood of that becomes less and less.  Additionally, the "wall of HTML" is going to be a pain to wade through if there are many of these elements on the page.  It's not like using AJAX POSTs is something radically new either...

Comment: @casperOne - the problem with using a link is that you expose the delete as a GET if there is a problem.  Unwrapping the forms using javascript on the client and applying a handler solves both problems.  You can use the action on the form when constructing the handler for the button and you never expose an anchor tag for a delete.  Another alternative would be to add the delete functionality dynamically - using `data` on a related element to build the routes - and only making it available if you have javascript working.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Whether or not it's a link is irrelevant; you can just as easily use a button with the above code and you'd get the same gains.  Also, you wouldn't be replicating form elements everywhere with the action replicated everywhere (no encapsulation).  Also, I really don't believe that javascript not working/enabled is a viable scenario nowadays; I'm not saying it *can't* happen, but the likelihood of it being the case is extremely rare.